# Can't get all http requests in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to access a site and check if no links redirecting to a page within the site that are down. As there is no sitemap available, I'm using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to crawl the site and get all links on every page, but I can't get it to output a file with all the links found and their status code. The site I'm using to test the code is quotes.toscrape.com and my code is:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from mytest.items import MytestItem
from scrapy.http
import Request
import re
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "sample"
    allowed_domains   = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com"]
    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
\# We stored already crawled links in this list
        crawledLinks = []
        for link in links:
\# If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
        if link not in crawledLinks:
             link = "http://quotes.toscrape.com" + link
             crawledLinks.append(link)
             yield Request(link, self.parse)
```

I've tried adding the following lines after yield:

```
item = MytestItem()
item['url'] = link
item['status'] = response.status
yield item
```

But it gets me a bunch of duplicates and no url with status 404 or 301. Does anyone know how I can get all the urls with the status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy by default does not return any unsuccessful requests, but you can fetch them and handle them in one of your functions if you set [`errback` on the request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).

```
def parse(self, response):
    # some code
    yield Request(link, self.parse, errback=self.parse_error)

def parse_error(self, failure):
    # log the response as an error
```

The parameter `failure` will contain [more information on the exact reason](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks) for failure, because it could be HTTP errors (where you can fetch a response), but also DNS lookup errors and such (where there is no response).

The documentation contains an example how to use failure to determine the error reason and access `Response` if available:

```
def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
    # log all failures
    self.logger.error(repr(failure))

    # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
    # you may need the failure's type:

    if failure.check(HttpError):
        # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
        # you can get the non-200 response
        response = failure.value.response
        self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

    elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
        # this is the original request
        request = failure.request
        self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

    elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
        request = failure.request
        self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get the 404 error logged, but I think that it was because the url was the robot.txt file. Do you know how I could get the urls and responses in a file though? Scrapy already shows me while it's running, but it doesn't create a file with them, even using -o file -t type.

Comment: Easiest method would be with the [feed exporters](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html). You just have to select the writing method (file based) and the format (CSV, JSON, ...). The options `FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` have to be added to `settings.py`. For a file based output, you'd set something like `FEED_FORMAT="file:///tmp/export.csv"`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#httperror-allow-all) in your settings or set the meta key `handle_httpstatus_all = True`in all your requests, please refer to the docs for more information.